# Error in Google play: exception.class.missing._Unknown_: TableInfo

Tags: android, android-room, sqlcipher, sqlcipher-android

I’ve noticed error happening in Google play, I couldn’t reproduce it, but it looks like it happens for small number of users.

```
exception.class.missing._Unknown_: TableInfo{...}
  at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade (RoomOpenHelper.java:103)
  at net.sqlcipher.database.SupportHelper$1.onUpgrade (SupportHelper.java:46)
  at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:182)
  at net.sqlcipher.database.SupportHelper.getWritableDatabase (SupportHelper.java:83)
  at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction (RoomDatabase.java:622)
  at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction (RoomDatabase.java:399)
```

Any idea why this happens? My guess is, because of R8 code shrinking, but I have no idea how to fix it.

I’m using Sqlcipher for Android 4.4.3 and Room 2.3.0

Thanks!